# Accounting for spatial dependence on 2D surface embedded in 3D using GAMs

Tags: r, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, spatial, mgcv

I want to infer if a dependent variable (DV) can be predicted by several independent variables (IVs). Their relationship is non-linear and monotonic so I chose to use a GAM. Using the *gam()* function of *mgcv*, my model would look something like this:

`model <- gam(dv ~ s(iv1) + s(iv2) + s(iv3), data = data, method = 'REML')`

However, I know that each of the IVs and the DV are spatially dependent; they are 2D maps embedded in 3D (surfaces) with values varying systematically across space. I want to take the spatial dependence into account such that inference about the IVs is robust. I have seen examples where people would use longitude and latitude as an interaction term to account for spatial dependence on a sphere. I don't have such a simple spherical coordinate system because I am working on a more complicated mesh. I do have the spatial relationships between vertices of that mesh and I am wondering if I could simply include spatial lags as fixed effects in my GAM to account for spatial dependence, as is commonly done in spatial regression? Are there any other options of using spatial relationships in a GAM? I've also seen others using longitude and latitude in the correlation structure of a GAMM.